# Cycle through VSCode Activity Bar icons

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to cycle throught VSCode Activity Bar (not Side Bar) with shortcuts, the same way as you would cycle through browser tabs?

If there's no system built-in way, is there any custom ways of achieving it, like using [multi-commands](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command) plugin? Though I'm not sure if multi-commands could do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [1.29 version](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_29#_workbench-navigation-commands)

```json
{
    "key": "ctrl+]",
    "command": "workbench.action.nextSideBarView",
    "when": "sideBarFocus"
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+[",
    "command": "workbench.action.previousSideBarView",
    "when": "sideBarFocus"
},
```

This way you can traverse even hidden views or skip some of them:

```json
{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+alt+i",
    "command": "workbench.action.findInFiles",
    "when": "activeViewlet == 'workbench.view.explorer'"
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+alt+i",
    "command": "workbench.view.scm",
    "when": "activeViewlet == 'workbench.view.search'"
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+alt+i",
    "command": "workbench.view.debug",
    "when": "activeViewlet == 'workbench.view.scm'"
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+alt+i",
    "command": "workbench.view.extensions",
    "when": "activeViewlet == 'workbench.view.debug'"
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+alt+i",
    "command": "workbench.view.explorer",
    "when": "activeViewlet == 'workbench.view.extensions'"
},
```